# Select object by color in an image?

Tags: python, image, object, image-processing, colors

Is there a way to find object that have specific color (for example red rectangle 100px 50px with white text) and then select that object as it is and cut it to new file? Look at the picture below. I'm trying to make a script for selecting data from image, then convert to text and finally write to Excel.

I googled a lot of howtos but didn't find any that address my problem.

[Sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AR87t.jpg)

Comment: There's a package called **OpenCV**, (CV = Computer Vision), that has Python bindings that can probably do what you want as far as selecting the objects goes.

Comment: Convert the image to HSV color space -> Extract contour regions with red color -> perform MSER for region inside those extracted red colored contours -> Tesseract will be able to read them

Answer (score 13):

I don't know your real intention, would you like only read the text or do you like also extract the parts?
Anyway, I'm going to show you a straight forward and general solution. Take the parts you need, at the end you find the hole code.

For the hole bunch you need **4** modules:
`cv2 (openCV)` for image processing
`numpy` to handle special operations on the images
`pytesseract` to recognize text (ocr)
`pillow (pil)` to prepare the image for pytesseract

**Load und filter**
Your original image:
[image: original]

First we reduce all colors except red. `lower` and `upper` describes the values from BGR (RGB = red, green, blue) we like to filter.

```
image = cv.imread("AR87t.jpg")

lower = np.array([0, 0, 200])
upper = np.array([100, 100, 255])
shapeMask = cv.inRange(image, lower, upper)

cv.imshow("obj shapeMask", shapeMask)
cv.waitKey(0)
```

This shows:
[image: shape mask]


**finding contours**
Next, we find the contours and iterating through. If we find 4 corners, we will do the next stuff...

```
cnts = cv.findContours(shapeMask.copy(), cv.RETR_EXTERNAL,
                       cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[0]

for c in cnts:
    peri = cv.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv.approxPolyDP(c, 0.04 * peri, True)
    if len(approx) == 4:
    ....
```

**mask the original**
With boundingRect, we extract `x`, `y`, `w`, `h`

```
(x, y, w, h) = cv.boundingRect(approx)
cv.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), thickness=5)
```

[image: mask]


**ocr on the mask**
And here comes the magic! First we extract the mask parts and export the openCV image to an PIL image. We are then able to run tesseract over.

```
el = shapeMask.copy()[y:y + h, x:x + w]
pil_im = Image.fromarray(el)

cv.imshow("obj", el)
cv.waitKey(0)

print(pytesseract.image_to_string(pil_im))
```

this shows you every rectangle as small image. You console will print out:

```
L2 = 33,33
L3 = 44,44
L1 = 12,22
```

**code**

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image



image = cv.imread("AR87t.jpg")

lower = np.array([0, 0, 200])
upper = np.array([100, 100, 255])
shapeMask = cv.inRange(image, lower, upper)

cv.imshow("obj shapeMask", shapeMask)
cv.waitKey(0)


cnts = cv.findContours(shapeMask.copy(), cv.RETR_EXTERNAL,
                       cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[0]

for c in cnts:
    peri = cv.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv.approxPolyDP(c, 0.04 * peri, True)
    if len(approx) == 4:
        (x, y, w, h) = cv.boundingRect(approx)
        cv.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), thickness=5)

        print("w:%s, y:%s, w:%s, h:%s" % (x, y, w, h))

        el = shapeMask.copy()[y:y + h, x:x + w]
        pil_im = Image.fromarray(el)

        cv.imshow("obj", el)
        cv.waitKey(0)

        print(pytesseract.image_to_string(pil_im))


cv.imshow("obj rectangle", image)
cv.waitKey(0)
```